# Error adding a JAR file to Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jar

I am trying to add the [this](https://github.com/ojas-webonise/ImageViewTouch/blob/master/bin/imageviewtouch.jar) jar file to my Android Studio project:

I did the necessary steps to add the jar as 'library'. But build gives me the following error:

```
Error:error reading C:\Users\Malik\AndroidStudioProjects\test6\app\libs\imageviewtouch.jar; error in opening zip file
tion timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a>
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a>
```

I tried adding another jar file I downloaded from somewhere and that didn't give the error.

Is this jar file corrupted or am I missing a dependency?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.greenbergc.test6"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile files('libs/about-0.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/imageviewtouch.jar')

}
```

Comment: show your Gridl file code..

Comment: Use Simplest method. Download the jar, Paste it in your project libs folder. Rebuild project or for some users you need to restsart Android Studio

Comment: Destro, I pasted it above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to add this jar file and successfully added without any error. I don't know how you add this file. This is the process that I use to add this jar file :

1. Downloaded this project from github.
2. Extract the project and get jar file from libs folder.
3. Now inside my project's libs folder, I simple paste this jar file.
4. **In android studio, go to libs folder -> right click on imageviewtouch jar file -> add as library.**
5. Done

Comment: Thanks Ruchir. I was making the mistake of downloading the jar by right clicking it. I guess downloading the file this way corrupts it. I did as you said and it is good now.